# Проблема при выгрузке файла формата pkl после его создания с теми же библотеками

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pickle

С помощью ген алгоритма создал модель для нейросети, сохранил его в файл формата pickle (.pkl).
Вот пример, что может содержать файл pkl

```
Layers for individual:

<keras.src.layers.attention.attention.Attention object at 0x0000022434098ED0>
<keras.src.layers.core.dense.Dense object at 0x00000224340998D0>
<keras.src.layers.rnn.lstm.LSTM object at 0x000002243409A410>
<keras.src.layers.regularization.dropout.Dropout object at 0x000002243409BA10>
<keras.src.layers.rnn.lstm.LSTM object at 0x000002243409B9D0>
<keras.src.layers.regularization.dropout.Dropout object at 0x00000224340A5F90>
<keras.src.layers.rnn.lstm.LSTM object at 0x00000224340A6E10>
<keras.src.layers.core.dense.Dense object at 0x00000224340AC650>
<keras.src.layers.regularization.dropout.Dropout object at 0x00000224340AC450>
<keras.src.layers.core.dense.Dense object at 0x00000224340A5ED0>
<keras.src.layers.regularization.dropout.Dropout object at 0x00000224340AC790>
<keras.src.layers.core.dense.Dense object at 0x00000224340AE750>

{'batch_size': 6821, 'validation_split': 0.4201392186482606, 'epochs': 5}
```

Библиотеки использованные в ген алгоритме:

```
import pickle
import random
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout, Attention
import tensorflow as tf
```

Библиотеки использованные в коде тренировке, то есть там где выгружается файл:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout, Attention
```

Код ген алгоритма и сохранение файла

```
# Генетический алгоритм
def genetic_algorithm(population_size, num_generations, mutation_rate):
    population = [generate_individual() for _ in range(population_size)]
    best_fitness_scores = []
    i = 0;

    for generation in range(num_generations):
        fitness_scores = evaluate_population(population)
        best_individual = get_best_individual(population, fitness_scores)
        best_fitness_scores.append(max(fitness_scores))

        print(f"Generation {generation + 1}, Best Fitness: {max(fitness_scores)}, Best Individual: {best_individual}")
        save_individual(f'best_individual_{variables["clines_time"]}.pkl',
                best_individual)
        parents = select_parents(population, fitness_scores)
        offspring = crossover(parents, population_size)
        mutated_offspring = mutate(offspring, mutation_rate)

        population = mutated_offspring  # Обновление списка population

    best_individual = get_best_individual(population, fitness_scores)
    best_fitness_scores.append(max(fitness_scores))

    print(f"Generation {num_generations}, Best Fitness: {max(fitness_scores)}, Best Individual: {best_individual}")

    return best_individual, best_fitness_scores


# Применение генетического алгоритма к модели
best_individual = genetic_algorithm(population_size, num_generations, mutation_rate)

# Сохранение лучших данных
save_individual(f'best_individual_{variables["clines_time"]}.pkl',
        best_individual)

print(' ')
print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print(' ')
```

Код для открытия файла

```
with open(f'individuals/best_individual_{variables["clines_time"]}.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    best_individual = pickle.load(f)
    best_individual = best_individual[0]
batch_size = best_individual[-1]['batch_size']
model = create_model_from_individual(best_individual)
validation_split = best_individual[-1].get('validation_split', 0.3)
```

Во время открытия постоянно вылезают ошибки по типу этой,

> ```
> best_individual = pickle.load(f)
>                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.layers.core'
> ```

Нужны советы как это решить